# Smart Thermostat with TWE040E13FB2

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have a trane TWE040E13FB2 hooked up to a heat pump. I am wanting to install a smart thermostat. Our current thermostat has 10 wires in it. I do not have a common wire. I also don't see a common wire on terminal block in the furnace. Is there a way to hook this up?[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you upload pictures showing all the wires as they are currently attached to the thermostat and to the furnace?

Comment: Yes, can you get us photos of both ends of the thermostat wiring please?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t add them yesterday. I was just notified of your responses this morning. I have read varying things that T or B could be the common. I have not checked T to have 24v yet. I was told on my unit that B was the common but it is hooked already to valve from heating to cooling I believe.

Comment: You probably don't need all 10 wires and the T terminal might be the common so you can probably free up a wire for that.  Please post a clear picture of the entire schematic.   Also, if you can locate where the two wires from the transformer are connected and trace them both into the handler, one will end up on R, the other will end up somewhere ... and that is C ... you can always splice in.  Post pics of that too if you find it.

Comment: You have wires connected to both WH/1 and WH/2 in the unit, but you also have them shorted together.   Do you have a secondary or emergency heat module or additional baseboard heat?       You have wires connected to S1 and S2 at the thermostat.  Those are for outside temperature sensors.  Where do the wires go?  Do you have those sensors?

Comment: We do have emergency backup heat and outdoor temp reading. The T does not have 24v at the smaller panel. I didn’t unplug anything and couldn’t be sure I was on the T terminal on the board but i believe I was and did not have voltage their either. The B does appear to be the common. But does it also do the valve? If so, could the splice be made behind the thermostat with a jumper instead of running a new wire?

Answer (score 1):

### Trane is silly

Trane is sometimes silly and calls their C wires B, which is mildly confusing because other brands sometimes use the B designation for the function that your O wire performs, namely heat-pump *reversing* control.  Anyway, you have a perfectly good C wire in disguise as your B wire, so just use that.

Comment: Could we find a stronger word than "silly" for wrapping the schematic around both sides of a small metal panel?    Anyway this answer is correct, in the photo with your finger in it you can easily trace the 24V common from the transformer to the B terminal where your wiring connects.  By the looks of things you have a blue wire connected to it, which at the thermostat is connected to a "B" terminal that may be Trane B or may be everyone else B.  Good luck mapping your Trane terminals to your new thermostat ones.  Good news, as this answer notes, is that you can.

Comment: @jay613 -- it's a Trane B since we already accounted for the O

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I did verify the B was the common. I still have a question though. I have the wiring going like this. 

R/rc > r/rc 
O > O
Y > Y
G > G
B > C
W2>W2
S1 and S2 which I believe are outdoor temp for heat anticipator will not be used and will be wire nutted in wall. Is this ok to do with them?

Where will the F (brown) and X2 (Black) wires go?

Comment: @Bbooth -- just cap the S1/S2 wires off separately, yes.  For the other two wires, we'll need to know what model your old and new thermostats are

Comment: The current model is a trane tcont802as32daa.  https://www.manualslib.com/manual/461448/Trane-Tcont802as32da.html?page=7#manual the new thermostat is a Honeywell RTH9585WF

Comment: @Bbooth -- connect the F wire (brown) to the L terminal of the new 'stat and cap off the X2 wire (black) since it's jumpered in parallel with the W2 connection